# Promise is not waiting for nest promises before resolving

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, promise, angular-promise

I have this initialization function that runs to set up global dependancies for my app I am using the npm package [angular-global-resolve](https://github.com/v1per/angular-global-resolve).  The package works fine, the problem is I have one big promise with nested promises in it in the initialization function and the main promise resolves before the nested ones, meaning certain things are not set the first time the app runs. How do I fix this?

My code: 
in routes.js:

```
  globalResolveProvider.addGlobalDependenciesTo($stateProvider, {
    getGlobalDependacies: function ($http, $rootScope, $cookies) {
      return $http.get('/__/env.json')
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log('then0')
        $rootScope.apiUrl = response.data.apiUrl;
        $rootScope.googleMapsApiKey = response.data.googleMapsApiKey;
        $rootScope.currentLocationLat = 40.7589;
        $rootScope.currentLocationLng = 73.9851;
        var hotelId = ''
        if ($cookies.get('hotel') === undefined){
          console.log('if 1')
          $http.get($rootScope.apiUrl + '/hotels')
          .then(function(dbHotels){
            console.log('then1')
            hotelId = dbHotels.data[0]._id
            $cookies.put('hotelId', hotelId)
          })
        }
        if ($cookies.get('userId') === undefined){
          console.log('if 2')
          $http.get($rootScope.apiUrl + '/users')
          .then(function(dbUsers){
            console.log('then2')
            var index = dbUsers.data.length - 1
            var userId = dbUsers.data[index]._id
            $cookies.put('userId', userId)
            $rootScope.$broadcast('update-itinerary-icon')
          })
        }
      })
      .then(function(){
        console.log("parent then is resolved")
      })
    }
  })
```

The console is logging:

```
then0
if 1
if 2
parent then is resolved
then1
then2
```

why does the parent then resolve before `then1` and `then2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
$http.get($rootScope.apiUrl + '/hotels')
```

Or:

```
$http.get($rootScope.apiUrl + '/users')
```

This only *begins* an HTTP request. Flow continues in the parent promise, without waiting for the nested GET to complete. And then the parent resolves as usual.

If you want to make the parent *wait* for a child promise, you must make the parent *return a promise*:

```
return $http.get($rootScope.apiUrl + '/hotels')
```

Now, if you want to make the parent wait for *multiple* child promises, you must return a *promise which composes multiple promises*. Inject `$q` into your function, and use this as your return statement:

```
return $q.all(
    $http.get($rootScope.apiUrl + '/hotels'),
    $http.get($rootScope.apiUrl + '/users')
);
```

If you want conditional logic, then you could try something like this:

```
return $q.all(
    ($cookies.get('hotel') === undefined)
    ? $http.get($rootScope.apiUrl + '/hotels')
    : $q.resolve(),
    ($cookies.get('userId') === undefined)
    ? $http.get($rootScope.apiUrl + '/users')
    : $q.resolve()
);
```

This makes it wait for an *already completed* promise, in the case where no work is necessary.

You can also add your `.then()` to the `$http.get()` in the above example.

Comment: Where do I put the .then? I tried this but it didn't seem to work: return $q.all( ($cookies.get('hotel') === undefined) ? $http.get($rootScope.apiUrl + '/hotels') .then(function(dbHotels){ console.log('then1') hotelId = dbHotels.data[0]._id $cookies.put('hotelId', hotelId) }) : $q.resolve()

Comment: Hm, that is indeed where you should put the `.then()`. I'm not sure why that's not working for you.

Comment: Yea, there weren't any errors, it's just that things were still happening out of order. I ended up fixing it a different way anyway, it turns out I didn't actually need to nest those two promises in the first one so I just made two more thens() after the first one and used the `return $http.get(..)`.  Thanks for your help.